# Make the navigationbar title clickable swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I would like to make the `navigationbar` title to be clickable. When user click on it, it should perform a segue. But I have no idea how to do this.

I have tried the following to get the title and apply the Tap gesture to it.

```
var subviews  = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
        if let subviews = subviews {
            // Better check for array length before accessing to the 1st element
            var subview = subviews [0]
        }
```

but its giving me error `Variable subview inferred to have type AvyObject, which may be unexpected`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

One more approach to add button as a title of navigation controller.

You need to set navigation item title view to your button object

Create button object in `viewDidLoad()` method:

**Swift 4.0 Edit**

```
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
button.backgroundColor = .red
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickOnButton), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.titleView = button
```

Here you can see in last line button is directly set to the `titleView` of `navigationItem` which will add button at the center of navigation bar.

Action method for button is below:

```
@objc func clickOnButton() {
}
```

Comment: I tried several ways like using UILabel and tap gesture but above all this solution was the cleanest, simplest and the most efficient way.

Comment: If you like the storyboard: You can also add a IBOutlet and then set the titleView to be this IBOutlet. self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Kampai's answer updated for Swift 3:

```
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickOnButton), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.titleView = button
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of that error, specify a type for your `if let` constant. I'd also recommend changing that `if let` constant name since it's the same as the one already declared in the previous line.

```
var subviews  = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
if let subviewArray:NSArray = subviews {
     // Better check for array length before accessing to the 1st element
     var subview:UILabel = subviewArray[0] // <-- If the subview's a UILabel
}
```

Comment: its still giving me the same problem.

Comment: and it wants me to change it to `subview:AnyObject`

Comment: @AtifFarrukh Yeah, the fact that it wants you to change it to subview:AnyObject is just a warning, but I'm personally not getting an *error* while running that code. There must be more to it...

Comment: so I just cleaned my project it gives me warning now. but I am not able to enable `subview.userInteractionEnabled = true`; this give error that `AnyObject does not have a member named userInteractionEnabled`

Comment: @AtifFarrukh Since you've accepted that answer, I see you have found a solution, but instead of changing it to "subview:AnyObject" you should have changed your line to  "subview:WhateverObjectTheSubviewIs". For example, if it's a UILabel: `subview:UILabel`