# add gesture recognizer uivew navigation bar swift not working

Tags: swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a navigation controller with a navigation bar, I have added a UIView with subview of imageView and UILabel for titleView.
I need to be able to click on that view to do something else with addGestureRecognizer on that view but nothing is printed on the console. 
The UIImageView has to be next to the UILabel

Here is the code I tried so far

```
private func setupNavBarWithUser() {
    let titleView = UIView()
    let width = titleView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).width
    titleView.frame = CGRect(origin:CGPoint.zero, size:CGSize(width: width, height: 500))

    let profileImageView = UIImageView()
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    ImageService.getImage(withURL: NSURL(string: (user?.pictureURL)!)! as URL) { (image) in
        profileImageView.image = image
    }
    titleView.addSubview(profileImageView)
    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    titleView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    nameLabel.text = user?.first_name
    nameLabel.textColor = .white
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    titleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.testing))
    titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    titleView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

@objc func testing() {
    print("hello")
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem, much thank you !!

[UPDATE this is where I need to add a gesture recognizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTCGa.png)

Answer (score 2):

Add this method in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear

```
 if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        // create a button
         let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2-20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
         button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.testing), for: .touchUpInside)
        // create a imageview
        let profileImageView = UIImageView()
         profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
         profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2-60, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "heart")
        // Add two elements to navigationbar
        navigationBar.addSubview(profileImageView)
        navigationBar.addSubview(button)

    }
```

[image: See this image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works but now there is not the imageView next to the label, I only have the nameLabel, how can I add it ?

Comment: just add tap gesture in viewwillAppear that's it

Comment: This work well, much thanks but now the tap gesture works even when I touch any icon bar on the left or right because the gesture is available on all the navigation bar, do you know how can fix it ?

Comment: you want to tap and do action on help and left arrow button ? don't want tap function on title ? .

Comment: I want to add action on titleView to be able to perform a zoom on the picture or title label but also be able to tap on the help button and the back button of the navbar to do other action

Comment: if you want to add action on titleView then create a button add to the titleview instead of creating label , you will get action also.
Here is the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632820/make-the-navigationbar-title-clickable-swift

Comment: I tried but only works with the button, I wasn't able to put the image View next to it :(

Comment: I updated my code check it once, if you want image action also then replace with uiimageview to uibutton

Comment: I just tried with my frames , if you want change the frame as your requirement

Comment: I tried the new code but this time nothing is on the navbar, I'm starting to despair .. :(

Comment: I manage to make it work by putting your code in viewDidLoad or viedDidAppear but now when I come back to the original view controller the navbar title is still here

Comment: @chandra1234 hii bro could u give me solution for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153355/how-to-create-top-navigation-like-reddit-app-in-swift-3