# How to center a bar button item in navigation bar in swift using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to have 3 `bar button items` in my `navigation bar` in my swift project.

I can drag/drop the buttons in my navigation bar using storyboard but the buttons will go to the left or right of the navigation bar!

I need to have 1 of these 3 buttons to sit in the middle of the navigation bar so I can use it as a Logo.

I've tried to use the `Flexible space bar item` as well with no success. I have nothing else in my navigation bar other than these 3 buttons.

could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: You want a button to be in center of Navigation bar? not tab bar?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, I've dragged the button onto the navigation bar and then dragged the flexible space bar button items on either side of it but they do nothing for some strange reason.

Comment: You need to add the button as title view to see the button in center, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632820/make-the-navigationbar-title-clickable-swift

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, yes, I need to center the button in the navigation bar. not tab bar.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, I need to be able to do this via Storyboard. is it possible?

Comment: I would recommend using a toolbar.

Comment: I dont think you can do that with story board, in storyboard you can only pass String as title cant pass a view so cant add a button